# Chrome Developer Tool Console does not like Jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but in my application when I try to do something like

```
$('#root').text();
```

I get

```
VM269:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null(…)
```

I have no clue why as I am referencing jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!--materialize does not understand jquery if I use it as import-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using reactjs but I don't think that should be a problem and the fact that I have no problems with firebug in firefox when I do the same command.

Edit

My bad `$('#test')` is something rendered into "root" div but same issue. So I just updated my query to do `$('#root').text()`

but doing `$('#root')` works it finds the element and like I said in firebug everything works.

Comment: In the console, can you access the element with `document.querySelector('#test')`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value from a tag with id='test' and you don't have one in your HTMl.
If you have used  `$('#root').val()` it'd work.

[Helpful selector link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the value of id="test". However, I do not see `id="test"` on your html file that you have included. Furthermore, you can also try `$('#test').text()` that will grab html text.